# Display the Image like Fade In using CABasicAnimation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, calayer, cabasicanimation

I am rotating the Image 360 clockwise using the CABasicAnimation, and the code which I am using is

```
CALayer*    _caLayer = [CALayer layer];
_caLayer.contents = (id)_logo.CGImage;  
_caLayer.frame = CGRectMake(65,158, 180,55);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:_caLayer];
CABasicAnimation*   rotation;
rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];    
rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
rotation.duration = 1.4f;
//rotation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() +1;
rotation.repeatCount = 2.0;
rotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[_caLayer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"360"];
```

The animation is working fine.. But I cant figure out one thing. I want to start animate the image from smaller size and ends with the normal size. You have seen in movies like some newspapers will rotate fast and they fade in and finally we will see the paper in the screen  fully. I am trying to do that way. I dont know how to do it, please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following also, will works like a charm

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fade in" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
_imageView.alpha = 0.0;
_newImageView.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the imageView frame before animation: `[imageView setFrame: CGRectMake(your Frame)];`

then keep on increasing the frame in the animation using a loop or something..